# Analyze c# code with sonarQube: MSBUILD version problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I need to analyze various C# files  (not a project, just .cs files put under the same directory).

I tried the analysis in 2 different ways and I have errors in each of it. Could someone help solve any of those errors?

1- I tried the analysis like mentioned [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes)

By executing C:\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat  in the root file, I have this error

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Custom and 3rd party Roslyn analyzers 
are only by MSBuild 14. Either use MSBuild 14, or disable the custom/3rd 
party Roslyn analyzers in your quality profile.
```

2- I tired creating a project and analyzing with [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild)

But at the end, I have this error that appears

```
The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect 
the required information about your projects.
Possible causes:
 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between 
the begin and end steps
 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. 
 Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
 3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the 
 same folder
 Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete 
 SonarQube analysis.
```

I have Visual Studio 2015,2012,2010,2008 installed. How can I verify that I am using the correct MSBUILD verison (14) because I checked C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild and I found the version 14 there.

Is there another issue to handle ?

At the end, I need to be able to do the analysis in both the first and seocnd way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the second way, is this project created with VS2015? If yes, you should add the MSBuild path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin" in to your system environment to make the begin, build or end steps are all launched from the same folder. It works fine on my machine. For the first way, could you please share us the detail steps how did you configure it?  We could not reproduce the first question without detail configuration info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
I added the msBuild Path as mentoined and the error has gone. Nevertheless, i need to analyze some .cs files only (I don't have a full project) which sound not possible with the second way. Please refer to this question link for more details of my issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920478/how-to-analyze-existing-cs-files-with-sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild?noredirect=1#comment76820131_44920478

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Glad to know that help you. I converted the comment to the answer, you can mark it as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. And I will continue investigate the question you mentioned in the comment, if I have any outcome, I will let you know in that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2- I tired creating a project and analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild

According to the document, we need execute following commands from the root folder of the project you want to analyze:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

But the command MSBuild.exe is a external command, can not be recognized by Windows in an arbitrary directory, you should **add the MSBuild path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin" in to your system environment** to make the begin, build or end steps are all launched from the same folder.