# How to analyze existing .cs files with SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to scan existing .cs files with sonarqube.

I understood that I need to use SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, and this one requires to create a project to analyze. So I created a project on Visual studio from existing files and declared it as Class Library. But while executing SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, I've got this error:

```
WARNING: The project has an invalid GUID "00000000-0000-0000-0000-
000000000000". The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project 
file: C:\Users\sas1\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\MSBuildTest\MSBuildTest.csproj
No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be 
performed. Check the build summary report for details.
Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete 
SonarQube analysis.
09:54:16.866  Creating a summary markdown file...
09:54:16.872  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

I can not create a console application with those files, because thus I will have many compilation errors, which I am not supposed to correct, since the code is not mine, but just delegated to me.

So my question is: if someone gives me several .cs files to analyze using SonarQube, how can I analyse them using SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't this person gives you the whole source code, including the Visual Studio configuration files? (because there are big chances that this person uses Visual Studio do develop this C# code)

Comment: Actually, we have too many several projects, and from each one, I need to analyze one specific file. So I collect them in one folder and need to analyze them.
So technically, I don't have to ananlyze the whole projects, I only need some files (about 5% of all the projects)

Comment: I tried using sonar runner instead of MSBuild, but it couldn't be possible with the existence of wintellectanalyzers-plugin (I need to develop custom rules) . I got this error: 
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Custom and 3rd party Roslyn analyzers 
are only by MSBuild 14. Either use MSBuild 14, or disable the custom/3rd 
party Roslyn analyzers in your quality profile.

Comment: I'm sorry but this "unusual" use case is not covered. I don't know the exact reason why you would analyse only 1 file per project, but if this is a strong requirement on your side, you won't be able to achieve this properly unless the dev teams bundle all of those files in a correctly-configured solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The only way i found to analyze a specific file is by using sonar runner without 3rd party Roslyn analyzer (ie by executing C:\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat in the folder having those files).  This is possible too for other languages ( php, java, javascript)
I just wanted to know if there is a difference between ananlyzing using sonar runner or SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, since the official documentation requires the use of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild and not sonar-runner. Thank you